# Getting next ID as PK for table insert

Tags: java, database, synchronization

I'm working on some old java code, and as part of an insert, the code makes a db call to get the last ID used in a table, then increments the ID, and uses the incremented ID as the next ID to use for the insert, as the PK.

It's a web application, and it seems to me that the same ID could be retrieved on a subsequent get ID call before the first/prior insert is done.

How would I prevent this, to ensure that the same ID is not reused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a transaction in your sql code.

Answer (score 0):

If you Database Server supports the [Auto Increment](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) attribute, then you can apply it to the ID column and it will assign itself incrementing unique IDs. The server does all the work and ensures that the ID is valid and unique.

Comment: sorry, forgot to say, i must do it in code, i cannot use that db feature in this case